# Python и установщик Django, Help

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь установить Django 2.x и выше, но выдает ошибку. На сколько я понял проблема в том, что при установке используется Python 2.7. (Версия 3.7 у меня установлена).[image: Сама ошибка]

Comment: `py -3.7 -m pip install django==2.2.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. По-хорошему, создайте виртуальное окружение из-под `python 3.7`, чтобы не устанавливать Джанго глобально.

```
virtualenv -p python3.7 py3env
```

2. Активируйте окружение

```
source py3env/bin/activate
```

3. Можете проверить, из под какого питона работает окружение, прописав `python` в командной строке.
4. Если там всё хорошо, то устанавливайте нужны вам пакеты (в данном случае Джанго)

```
pip install Django==2.2.5
```